# Interacting with USER OU in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

`User` is not your typical `OU` in Active Directory and I am trying to interact with it to pull its information down. If I run

`get-adorganizationlunit -filter 'name -eq "User"'`

I receive no output which I guess I expected, but how can I interact with it?  I am writing a script to create OU's from a CSV file and we need sub OUs to be added under User. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Users is not an organizational unit, but rather a container. Try runnning `Get-ADObject -Filter {Name -eq 'Users'}` to get back the Users object; you'll see that it's ObjectClass is 'container', and not 'Organizational Unit.' You cannot create OU's under containers, such as Users. So you'll need to create these new OU's somewhere else.

Comment: `Container` that is the word I was searching for...I knew it wasn't an OU but I was still hoping I could have modified it. My workaround was to create my own structure though probably not best practice, the requirements do not allow me to change this.